# When does Jasmine reset the spies?

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, ng-mocks

I have found this code:

```
describe('Test', function() {
  const NAVIGATOR = window.navigator;

  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOnProperty(window.navigator, 'userAgent').and.returnValue('Mozilla');
  })

  afterEach(function() {
    window.navigator = NAVIGATOR;
  });
}
```

Why is the code in `afterEach` needed? As far as I know, Jasmine resets spied-on functions after each spec with their normal implementation again. Looking in the docs also confirms that. So why is this needed? Is there something special here?

Answer (score 0):

You are right about that but `Jasmine` will automatically restore spied on functions after each test runs. So the `afterEach` rest here is likely redundant and not needed.

The key thig is the `spyOnProperty` is spying on the `userAgent` property of the `navigator` object. It is not replacing the entire `navigator` object.

So after each test, the `userAgent` property will be restored to it's original value automatically.

Resetting the entire `navigatore` object back to the original `NAVIGATOR`const is unnecessary.

A couple of things that may explain why it's there:

- Might be incorrectly assumed Jasmine doesn't reset spied properties. So manually reset it just to be safe.
- There may have been some specific issue or edge case with the testing framework/environment used that required manually resetting the navigator.
- It was copy-pasted from somewhere else without understanding if it's needed.

But in general with `Jasmine`, you don't need to manually reset spied properties or functions in a `afterEach`. They will be handled automatically.

So In this case, the `afterEach` reset of `navigator` is likely redundant and can removed. The spied `userAgent` property will be restored correctly on its own after each test.

---

I hope this will help you. Cheers